# Laravel shows urls with http instead of https

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 7 and website is running on https but it shows all links to http.

i am using
below code to redirect for all pages.

```
<a href="{{url('about')}}">About></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `config/app.php` you should have a `url` entry to set like:

```
'url' => 'https://your-website.domain'
```

otherwise you can use the `boot` method of `AppServiceProvider` adding this:

```
\URL::forceScheme('https');
```

Comment: Hey Alberto, Thanks let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: @Amit sure, let me know

Comment: Hey Alberto its https with domain name already there. No Luck

Comment: have you tried with the second snipped? @Amit

Comment: no i don't know how to use that where to use that.

Comment: @Amit literally search for a file called `AppServiceProvider` and inside the `boot` method (that you will see inside that file) add that line of code

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when running a Laravel application behind an NGINX proxy and the communication internally was running via HTTP. So, the request reached Laravel as HTTP.

The solution from Alberto was fixing it. Here is the code I have added to the `boot()` method of the `AppServiceProvider`:

```php
if (config('app.env') === 'production' || config('app.env') === 'staging') {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey all who use NGINX proxy

Don't use *URL::forceScheme('https');*

Just add: **proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;**

```
location / {
    ...
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
```